# Why won't image texture load in X3DOM?

Tags: html, x3d, x3dom

I'm working with X3DOM for the 1st time (although I did a lot of VRML back in the day.

I'm trying a simple example with a image file for a texture, but the image never loads. Here's what I see (using Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 m): 
[image]
The circle spins forever and the Loading: 1 stays. I have the same problem on another file (except it has 7 images, and the message reads "Loading: 7".

Here's my code:

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8'></meta>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.css'></link>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.x3dom.org/x3dom/release/x3dom.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <x3d width='500px' height='400px'> 
    <scene> 
    <shape> 
    <appearance> 
    <ImageTexture  url="wood11.png"><ImageTexture/>
    </appearance> 
    <box> </box> 
    </shape> 
    </scene> 
    </x3d>

</body>
</html>`

The image is present and stored in the same directory. Why won't images load for me?

Comment: You can't load textures if you are not using a proper web server since they are loaded via XHR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in Mozilla Firefox so you can test it there.
Chrome throws a security exception because the image is not served by a server.

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': 
Tainted canvases may not be loaded.image.onload @ x3dom.js:377
```

You can find the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945945/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-loaded-cross-domain-issue-with-webgl-textures).

And some other pertinent information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/Tutorial/Using_textures_in_WebGL#Cross-domain_textures).

> Loading of WebGL textures is subject to cross-domain access controls.
>   In order for your content to load a texture from another domain, CORS
>   approval needs to be be obtained. See HTTP access control for details
>   on CORS.

Comment: Here's the strange thing. If I put it on a webserver, it works great from Chrome, BUT, while I can view several of the simple examples at examples.x3dom.org in Firefox on the same machine, I CAN'T view the above example in Firefox. If I just try locally without a server, I get just an empty white bounding box for the scene, while from a webserver, I get a filled in black bounding box. So the core problem of viewing in Chrome is solved, something funny is still going on (hence why a +1, not yet an accepted answer).

Comment: you need to use a debugger (e.g. Firebug: https://getfirebug.com/downloads) to find out  which is the error in a case or another. Otherwise it would be just a guess...

Comment: Got it. Apparently some of my browsers are using the swf viewer, which I hadn't installed on my server, so the cross-domain issue popped up with them for a different reason (swf file and textures were on different hosts) when I viewed them from my hosting site. I'll fix that tonight.  P.S.: what's REALLY weird now is that my home IE browser loads the textures for a scene I'm working on (more complex then the one above) BUT some objects are out of place. I don't get that with IE at work, with Chrome, with Firefox, or with Safari on my iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

You can base64 encode your texture.

```
<ImageTexture url="data:image/png;base64,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"></ImageTexture>
```