# Three.js : Texture from an IP Camera

Tags: javascript, security, camera, three.js, textures

So I'm having some troubles to put the video of an Axis Camera into a Texture.
The Axis Camera is returning the wanted video into a picture. The picture src is the camera IP address.

I wanted to put directly the picture into the texture, but I got an error from the Cross-origin resource sharing... I did some research on Internet and I found this [link](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Webcam-Texture.html). Therefore, I wrote the exact same code and it worked well with the webcam, and the 71st version of Three Js ! However, when I wanted to test it with my axis camera, it was sending me the same error :

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': Tainted canvases may not be loaded.
```

Does someone have an idea about how to solve this problem ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945945/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-loaded-cross-domain-issue-with-webgl-textures

Comment: Well, I already see that topic and I tried his solution to put the attribute croosOrigin to "anonymous", but I got this error : 
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.

Answer (score 0):

I finally get it ! So it's indeed a CROS problem. Put just the crossOrigin image at "anonymous" wasn't the good solution, because the CROS was always a problem, since the picture I want to use is from another IP address...


So what I needed to do is only to put some attributes to Chrome :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="D:\chrome"
```

And that's working ! ^u^ Warning though, you need to create another shortcut exclusively for your work and you mustn't use that to search on the internet !