# libgdx GWT. Create Texture from url

Tags: java, gwt, libgdx

I need help. 
I need display jpg image from url.

Desktop version work fine

```
byte[] imgBytes
new Pixmap(imgBytes, 0, imgBytes.length)
```

But it is not work in GWT project. 
I try this solution ["Tainted canvases may not be loaded" Cross domain issue with WebGL textures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945945/tainted-canvases-may-not-be-loaded-cross-domain-issue-with-webgl-textures/30956367#30956367)

```
public void downloadPixmap(final String url, final DownloadPixmapResponse response) {
    final RootPanel root = RootPanel.get("embed-html");
    final Image img = new Image(url);
    img.getElement().setAttribute("crossOrigin", "anonymous");
    img.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
            HtmlLauncher.application.getPreloader().images.put(url, ImageElement.as(img.getElement()));
            response.downloadComplete(new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal(url)));
            root.remove(img);
        }
    });
    root.add(img);
}

interface DownloadPixmapResponse {
     void downloadComplete(Pixmap pixmap);       
     void downloadFailed(Throwable e);
}
```

but it is work only in Chrome browser. It is not work in Mozilla Firefox.
Help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in url. Some url do not have header 
**Access-Control-Allow-Origin ***

That is why images do not display. I fix this using nginx. 
Here link to my settings, my problems  and ansvers
https://serverfault.com/questions/816080/nginx-proxy-pass-regexp-to-another-domain